# Otra mas de Facebook login y recuperar email de registro

Tags: facebook, permisos, facebook-api, sdk

Estoy implementando el Facebook login a una web app y necesito recuperar el email para agregarlo al registro de app, pero la api de Facebook solo me devuelve el id y el nombre, revise en los permisos y deberia tener agregado el email, en la documentacion se declara que no es necesaria una revision para tenerlo habilitado, pero no logro que el cuadro de dialogo anuncie que se requerira el email y tampoco capturarlo, en las herramientas de debug logro agregarlo y luego recuperarlo, pero no se podra estar haciendo eso a cada usuario que se valide, alguna idea de que estara mal? Lei y lei, y la app debe estar publicada para capturar datos, y ya lo esta, en la configuracion de la app, el permiso de email me sale validado (en verde) asi como el facebook profile (requerido)

Gracias por su atencion,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final se arreglo solo, pero note que solo se arreglo despues de poner el codigo del boton de Facebook minimo, mi implementacion lleva un "custom" button para poder aplicarle estilos, entonces agregue el boton y lo oculte y agregue los scopes de email y name en la llamada a FB.login, quedo asi:

```html
<div class="hidden">
  <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email">
  </fb:login-button>
</div>

<button id="fb-login" onClick="logInWithFacebook();" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-long fb-login-button" scope="public_profile,email">
<span><i class="fab fa-facebook color-white"></i></span> <span>Log in with Facebook</span>
</button>
```

y la llamada al script asi:

```html
<script>
  logInWithFacebook = function() {

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === "connected") {
        // The user is logged in and has authenticated your
        // app, and response.authResponse supplies
        // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
        // request, and the time the access token 
        // and signed request each expire.
        let uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        let accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        window.location.replace("/dashboard/auth/login/fblogin");
      } else if (response.status === "not_authorized") {
        // The user hasn't authorized your application.  They
        // must click the Login button, or you must call FB.login
        // in response to a user gesture, to launch a login dialog.
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
              console.log("Logged and cookie set");
              // Now you can redirect the user or do an AJAX request to
              // a PHP script that grabs the signed request from the cookie.
              window.location.replace("/dashboard/auth/login/fblogin");
            } else {
              console.log("User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.");
              removeClass(loader, "active");
            }
          },{scope : "email,public_profile"});
      } else {
        // The user isn't logged in to Facebook. You can launch a
        // login dialog with a user gesture, but the user may have
        // to log in to Facebook before authorizing your application.
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
              console.log("Logged and cookie set");
              // Now you can redirect the user or do an AJAX request to
              // a PHP script that grabs the signed request from the cookie.
              window.location.replace("/dashboard/auth/login/fblogin");
            } else {
              console.log("User cancelled login or did not fully authorize");
            }
          },{scope : "email,public_profile"});
      }
     });


    return false;
  };  

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'API_ID',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v7.0'
    });

    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   

  };
</script>
<script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

Espero a alguien mas le sirva